# Oracle SQL - How Many Rows Searched Until Query Finished?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the query:

```
select * from mytable where <condition> and rownum <= k;
```

Can I augment it to form a query that will tell me how many rows were searched throughout the query's execution?

Comment: That is a rather curious request.  SQL queries describe the result set.  The optimizer can choose to execute this however it wishes.  You would need to go through the statistics of the execution plan to get information like that.

Comment: If the condition is served by an index it might not "search" any row at all! What is the reason for wanting to know that?

Comment: To obtain a cursory statistic for a very large database.  I am using a manual workaround for now.

Comment: Do you really care about the number of rows searched or do you just need the amount of time spent on each operation?  SQL Monitor reports are usually the fastest way to find out which operations are slow in a SQL statement.  Using the "Activity (%)" value you can focus on the slow operations in a plan and ignore the fast parts.  But it only gives the *output* row counts for each operation, not necessarily the number of rows searched.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for here, but thanks, that will certainly be useful to me in the future.  I will go investigate that now.